# express jade upgrade to latest throwing error

Tags: node.js, express, pug

My app was running fine with express, jade etc.
Today when I upgraded this to latest express and jade, using `npm update express jade`, it started throwing the following error when i try to access the site. Is it expecting a package.json ?

I am not using package.json, but rather using NODE_ENV to point to C:\Personal\software\nodejs\NODE where all my node modules are installed.

```
Error: Cannot find module './lib/jade'
    at Function._resolveFilename (module.js:332:11)
    at Function._load (module.js:279:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
    at require (module.js:370:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Personal\software\nodejs\NODE\node_modules\jade\index.js:2:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:441:26)
    at Object..js (module.js:459:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:348:31)
    at Function._load (module.js:308:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
```

Comment: downgraded to jade 0.20.0 and it's working now.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem today, just download the zip file from github https://github.com/visionmedia/jade, unpack it and drop it over your existing jade folder to  overwrite it.